# Pluralize/singularize a sentence using the compromise library in javascript

Tags: javascript, nlp, pluralize

I'm trying to use the [compromise](https://github.com/spencermountain/compromise) library to pluralize/singularize sentences that take these forms:

```
const str1 = "10 dog";
const str2 = "a man and 3 cat";
const str3 = "a bear";
```

If I use the `pluralize` method from compromise, it returns the list of plural nouns or verbs, but I'm trying to figure out how to get it to pluralize the entire string.

```
const nlp = require("compromise");
const doc = nlp(str2);
const finalStr = doc.nouns().toPlural().out("normal"); // "man cats" instead of "a man and 3 cats";
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work because it will identify all the nouns first:

`doc.match("#Noun").nouns().toPlural().out("normal");`

#### edit

I see where the problem came from. Take a look at below two console logs:

```
const nlp = require("compromise")
let doc = nlp("a man and 3 cat")
doc.match("#Noun").nouns().toPlural()
console.log(doc.out("normal")) // "a man and 3 cats"

let doc2 = doc.match("#Noun").nouns().toPlural()
console.log(doc2.out("normal")) // "man cats"
```

Note that in the second example, I am saving it into a new variable. So I guess `.match("#Noun")` was not necessary, and you were right the first time -- just don't save it into `finalStr`.

Comment: It looks like I had a typo in my comment. Your code produces `"man cats"` instead of `"a man and 3 cats"`. Maybe I'm using the wrong library?

Comment: @KevinWhitaker Maybe check the version? https://runkit.com/kkj6781/nlp-compromise-tosingular-toplural

Comment: @KevinWhitaker Updated my answer. Please see the edited part.

Comment: that worked. Weird - I guess saving it to a new variable mutates it somehow. Thanks!